# Sending binary data over gevent websocket

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, compression

I need to send a pickled python dictionary containing several, large Pandas Dataframes over a websocket (Python API at both ends). To improve performance, I would like to compress the pickled object before sending it over the websocket. However, when doing this, the received message is always None.

Client:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4]})
d = dict(b=df)
msg = zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(d),5)
socket.send(msg)
```

Server:

```
msg = socket.receive()
# msg is always None when called with client code above.
data = pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(msg))
```

Is there a better way to do this?
I am using gevent-websocket through the Flask-Sockets framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send binary data in Python 2.7, you must set `binary=True` in the client (ws4py):

```
socket.send(msg, Binary=True)
```

As another note, on the receiving side, you will need to wrap the msg in a buffer before sending to zlib.decompress()

```
msg = socket.receive()
data = pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(buffer(msg)))
```